# What's the term for a phrase made of two words that have the same meaning?

Tags: terminology, repetition

Sometimes we place two words together that have the same meaning, thus making one of the words unnecessary. Examples:

1. **Body corporate** ('corporate' comes from Latin 'corpus', which means 'body'), so it's like saying "body body".
2. **Naan bread** ('naan' means 'bread' in Hindi), therefore it's like saying "bread bread".

Is there a term for these kind of phrases in English?

Comment: I would call "naan bread" a back formation, enlisted as an adjective to distinguish *naan* from other kinds of bread (cf. "acoustic" guiitar, etc.). No opinion on "body corporate."

Comment: @Robusto, sorry, it was probably not the best example with "naan bread". My point was that it would be sufficient just to say "naan", like they do in Hindi, instead of adding redundant word "bread". What I wanted to know is if there a term for these kind of phrases?

Comment: In general using redundant words is called a "tautology." https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tautology#

Comment: Not an answer, but there is "River Avon" where Avon is a misspelling of the Welsh Afon = River.

Comment: The question is based on a mistaken assumption that one of the words in each pair is unnecessary. If they really were unnecessary, then the answer would be the one given by Mr. Fine. These words, however, seem unnecessary only if one focuses on their etymology and ignores the specific meanings they have, over time, acquired in English.

Comment: @PeterJennings: I would be surprised if *Afon* were not pronounced the same as *Avon*, since that is how it would have been rendered in Old English and may have come down to use with spelling and pronunciation intact. Or I could be wrong about that. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto I'm sure you have a point, but you can imagine the conversation:
Englisman "What'sthat called? - 
Welsman "Afon" - 
Englishman "Oh, so it's the River Avon"

Comment: @Peter: I'm just saying they're probably the same word with a variant spelling but the same pronunciation.

Comment: @Robusto No argument, I agree with you. Particularly as spelling was not well defined for many years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one kind of [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm)

(Incidentally, I don't agree that "body corporate" is an example: your argument is an example of the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). There are meanings of "body" and "corporate" which overlap, but their core meanings in modern English are quite separate. ).

Comment: Although, as stated in comments, _naan bread_ doesn't really fit either, since (at least in other parts of the world) naan bread is distinguished from other types of bread.